# Variable length array types in function prototype scope

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning about `VLA`s and wrote the following example:

```
struct array_t{
    const size_t length;
    const char data[];
};

struct array_t *create(const size_t n, const char data[n]){
    const size_t data_offset = offsetof(struct array_t, data);
    struct array_t *array = malloc(data_offset + n * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(&(array -> length), &n, sizeof(n));
    memcpy(&(array -> data), data, n);
    return array;
}
```

So I tested it with

```
char ca[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
struct array_t *array_ptr = create(5, ca);
```

and it compiles fine (unfortunately). As I figured out `6.7.6.2(p5)`:

> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
>   expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope,
>   it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise, each time it is
>   evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.

So obviously `n` is not a constant expression and `const char data[n]` is simply treated as `const char*` which is not what I wanted.

So is there any reason of such arrays declarations if they don't give any type safety? Maybe we can write some macro function that will do the following:

```
#define create_array_t //...

const char a1[5];
const char a2[10];
const char *a_ptr;

create_array_t(5, a1); //fine
create_array_t(5, a2); //error
create_array_t(5, a_ptr); //error
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, do you mean *variable length arrays* or *flexible array members*?

Comment: @StephanLechner Sorry, bad wording. Flexible array member for sure.

Comment: Note: by saying `create(5, ca);`, where `ca` is of `char [3]`, aren't you breaking the contract?

Comment: Side note, you don't need the (error prone) business with `data_offset`. `sizeof(array_t)` gives the correct result, alignment for the FAM and all.

Comment: @StoryTeller But `sizeof(struct array_t)` returns 8 on my machine which. If I allocate only 8 bytes I cannot copy the actual content into the object...?

Comment: ... You still need to allocate for the FAM. The sizeof replaces `data_offset`

Comment: @StephanLechner: The title and the body of the question ask about variable length arrays. The code also copies the array passed as a parameter into a flexible array member, but that is not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the function allocating room for a struct with a flexible array member should be like this:

```
array_t* create (const size_t n, const char data[n])
{
  array_t* array = malloc( sizeof(array_t) + sizeof(char[n]) );
  array->length = n;
  memcpy(array->data, data, n);
  return array;
}
```

> So is there any reason of such arrays declarations if they don't give any type safety?

Good compilers can theoretically omit warnings, though I don't think there are any that does. Static analysers will warn.

However, the main reason is self-documenting code. You create a tight coupling between the size variable and the array variable.

> Maybe we can write some macro function

Sure, with standard ISO C we can write a wrapper macro to increase type safety and take advantage of the VLA notation. Something like this:

```
#define create_array_t(n, array)      \
  _Generic(&array,                    \
           char(*)[n]:       create,  \
           const char(*)[n]: create) (n, array)
```

The trick here is to dodge the array decay by using &, to take an array pointer. Then compare if the array type matches that pointer, before calling `create` with the parameters passed.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
  size_t length;
  char data[];
} array_t;

array_t* create (const size_t n, const char data[n])
{
  array_t* array = malloc(sizeof(array_t) + sizeof(char[n]));
  array->length = n;
  memcpy(array->data, data, n);
  return array;
}

#define create_array_t(n, array)      \
  _Generic(&array,                    \
           char(*)[n]:       create,  \
           const char(*)[n]: create) (n, array)

int main (void)
{
  const char a1[5];
  const char a2[10];
  const char *a_ptr;

  (void) create_array_t(5, a1);    // fine
//(void) create_array_t(5, a2);    // error _Generic selector of type 'const char(*)[10]' is not compatible
//(void) create_array_t(5, a_ptr); // error _Generic selector of type 'const char**' is not compatible

  return 0;
}
```

This can be further improved by making `array_t` an opaque type, hiding the struct implementation inside a .c file and get an object-oriented ADT with private encapsulation.

Comment: Very interesting to see useful use-case of `_Generic`. But as I read in the Standard `The type name in a generic association shall specify a complete object type other than a variably modified type`. I tried the following `char data[5]; const size_t n = 5; create_array_t(n, data);` and it does not compile. The question if such usage of VM types with Generic Selection is UB and the error message I see is the implementation details of `GCC`?

Comment: @SomeName Yikes, I didn't know that! Well, that means that the above code will work, but not a VLA. Using VLA isn't UB but worse, a constraint violation. I swear, the committee must actively be striving to make all new language features as useless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> memcpy(&(array -> length), &n, sizeof(n));
> memcpy(&(array -> data), data, n);
> ```

You abuse here the contract with the compiler. You promise to do not change any of struct members but you try to find the workaround for it. **It is an extremely bad practice**

So if you want to assign or copy values runtime you **must not** declare it `const`. Otherwise you do the worst. You declare something const - which can be assigned only during the initialisation, but you use it as a not `const` object. You break the logic of correct "constantness."

If you want to dynamically allocate memory for such a structs do not make members const.

You can later make the pointer to the const struct when declaring another functions which will use that object

```
typedef struct{
    size_t length;
    char data[];
}array_t;

array_t *create(const size_t n, const char data[n])
{
    array_t *array = malloc(sizeof(array_t) + n);
    array -> length = n;
    memcpy(array -> data, data, n);
    return array;
}

void do_something(const array_t *prt)
{
    ....
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The question asks about the function parameter, a variable length array This answer does not answer that question. The issue it addresses could have been raised in a comment, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I do not agree.

Comment: Where does this answer say anything about the parameter? Where does the question ask anything about the structure?